# CakePHP: How to make auto-increment values contiguous again after deleting rows

Tags: php, database, cakephp, increment

I have a blog with 4 remaining posts. The posts' ids are: 0, 1, 8, and 10. This is because I've deleted posts 2-7 and post 9. Is there any what I can "fix" these posts' ids so that in my database table they go from 1 - 3 and are contiguous?

Comment: You *don't*. You can, but you absolutely should not. The field with AI is likely a surrogate key and in that case changing them will break your database schema. If your rows need contiguous numbering then you shouldn't be using AI in the first place.

Comment: I agree, better to rely on slug based urls, maybe even with a date - similar as Wordpress does it. This is also better for readability/autocomplete in browsers and for SEO. The ID itself doesnt matter (and if its continuous or not).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can drop the MySQL column manually, then re-add it with the same properties. The rows will be reordered.

Alternatively, use these commands:

```
SET @count = 0;
UPDATE `users` SET `users`.`id` = @count:= @count + 1;
```

Replace `users` and `id` appropriately.

You can reset your auto incrementing id column also with:

```
ALTER TABLE `users` AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;
```

Where users is replaced with the name of your table.

Answer (score 0):

you can change their ids manually and then set the value of the auto_increment

```
alter table users auto_increment 5
```